# AWS assign external role to instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I have a program that goes through many accounts and does inventory.  Right now it is using boto3 and AWS keys.

I would like to move away from aws keys and instead assign role to an instance and use that role to switch accounts.

I know how to assign external role to a user, but I have no idea how to do that with an instance role.

The idea here is to do something like this:

1. Get list of all accounts from main organization account
2. For each account assume role with ec2 (and other service) describe role
3. Get inventory
4. Switch role to another account.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is sound. You would do it as follows:

- Create a **Main Role** in the main account.
- Assign this role to the Amazon EC2 instance being used to gather the inventory.
- Create a **Target IAM Role** in each target account.

  - Assign sufficient permissions to each Target Role to allow the inventory (eg `Describe*` calls)
  - Edit the **Trust Policy** on each Target Role to permit the **Main Role** to use the **Target Role**

Your application can then use the **Main Role** (assigned to the EC2 instance) to call `AssumeRole()` on each of the **Target Roles** in the child accounts (as per your step 2).

Thus, your flow is really:

1. Get list of all accounts from main organization account
2. For each account:

   - Assume Role on the target role
   - Get inventory

Comment: OMG I am an idiot! THANK YOU!
I know what I've been doing wrong.  I needed to assume role, then use the dictionary I get from that as my credential tokens! Assuming role doesn't actually switch to that role.  I completely missed that piece.

Answer (score 0):

You can call org API to list accounts first and the same way you can call for each account with cross-account role
Make sure your Ec2 role has sufficient permissions to assume role for child account

````
def get_accounts():
    sts_role = 'arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/AWSAudit_CrossOrgAccess'  # Org Billing API 
    assumedRoleObject = sts.assume_role(RoleArn=str(sts_role), RoleSessionName="accounts_watcher_lambda" )
    credentials = assumedRoleObject['Credentials']
    conn = boto3.client( 'organizations', aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'], aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],)
    list_of_accounts = conn.list_accounts() 

    return list_of_accounts```


## Your Ec2 role looks like 

`
YourServerEc2Profile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: '/'
      Roles:
      - Ref: YourServerEc2Role
YourServerEc2Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
      -
        PolicyName: AuditInstall
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            -
              Action:
                - "ssm:*",
                - "ec2:DescribeImages",
                - "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
                - "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                - "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                - "ec2:DescribeTags",
                - "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                - "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                - "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                - "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                - "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                - "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"
              Resource: "*"
              Effect: "Allow"

      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Ref YourServerCrossAccount
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess
  YourServerCrossAccount:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
          Resource:
          - arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/AWS_CrossAccount
`
````